# 8バイトにアライメントされていないchar *型を整数型にキャストした時エラーが起きないのはなぜですか？

Tags: c, ポインタ

sのアライメントを意図的にずらしてuint64_t型にキャストしたあとそのアドレスを参照したら、アライメント制約に違反しているのでエラーになるかと思ったのですが、正常に動いてしまいました。なぜですか？

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int     main()
{
    char *s = strdup("\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0");

    if (!((uintptr_t)s % 8))
        s++;
    printf("%lu\n", *(uint64_t *)s);
}
```

実行環境は下記の通りです

CPU ryzen 5 3600
OS windows10 64bit上のvirtual boxでUbuntu 18.04.5 LTSを起動
コンパイラ clang
オプション -Werror -Wall -Wextra

Comment: 使っているCPU、OSおよびそのbit数、コンパイラ、コンパイラオプションなど諸々の条件によるのでは？ それらの情報を追記してみてください。あるいはたまたまかもしれませんね。デバッガの逆アセンブラモード等でステップを追ってみれば分かりそうです。

Comment: すいません！
CPU ryzen 5 3600
OS  windows10 64bit上のvirtual boxでUbuntu 18.04.5 LTSを起動
コンパイラ clang
オプション -Werror -Wall -Wextra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

インテルx86/x64アーキテクチャのCPUには(一部の命令/データ以外では)個々のメモリアクセスでのアライメント制約は無いですよ。

[x86 - データ構造アライメント - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88#x86)

> x86アーキテクチャは本来、アライメントされたメモリアクセスを必要とせず、またそれなしでは動作するが、x86 CPUのSSE2命令の中には、データを128ビット（16バイト）にアライメントさせる必要があるものがあり、これらのアーキテクチャでアライメントされたデータを使用することにより、パフォーマンス上の大きな利点が得られる。ただし、MOVDQUなどのアラインされていないアクセスのための命令もある。さらに、ロードとストアの操作は、通常、正しくアラインされていればアトミックである。

[３.１ アラインメントに寛容な CPU の場合 (alignment-tolerant processors) - データ型のアラインメントとは何か，なぜ必要なのか？](http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Enoocyte/Programming/Alignment.html#AlignmentTolerantCPU)

> このようなＸを読み書きするように命令された CPU はどうするだろうか？  「２回に分けて読み書きする」と思うだろう．x86 は実際そのように動作する (ただし後述する場合を除く)．

[３.２ アラインメントに厳格な CPU の場合 (alignment-strict processors) - データ型のアラインメントとは何か，なぜ必要なのか？](http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Enoocyte/Programming/Alignment.html#AlignmentStrictCPU)

> x86 以外の多くの CPU (特に RISC) は上記のようには動作せず，エラーとして処理する． つまり「不正アラインメント例外注3」を発生させる．

大部分のアクセスでは、多少アドレスをずらしても、そこからuint64_tのサイズ分が全て読み取り有効な領域に収まっていれば(ページメモリ境界ギリギリとかでなければ)、例外は発生しないでしょう。

---

ちなみに、以下の部分は`アライメントを意図的にずらす`処理としては不適切では？
丁度8バイト境界の時には`s++`の処理は実行されないように見えます。
元々8バイト境界に収まっていない時だけ`s++`が実行されるように見えます。

```
    if ((uintptr_t)s % 8)
        s++;
```

Comment: >元々8バイト境界に収まっていない時だけs++が実行されるように見えます。

ほんとですね！ミスってました、修正しておきます、すいません.
x86にはないんですね。全然知りませんでした。そういうところもCPUによって違っているんですね。勉強になりました！ありがとうございました。