# x86では、ワードサイズより大きいアライメントされていないデータを読み出す場合、メモリアクセス回数は増えますか？

Tags: c, assembly, memory

**実行環境**
CPU ryzen 5 3600
OS windows10 64bit上のvirtual boxでUbuntu 18.04.5 LTSを起動
アセンブラ　nasm
オプション -f elf64
コンパイラ　clang
オプション -O0

[8バイトにアライメントされていないchar *型を整数型にキャストした時エラーが起きないのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/8%e3%83%90%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84char-%e5%9e%8b%e3%82%92%e6%95%b4%e6%95%b0%e5%9e%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%82%ad%e3%83%a3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%99%82%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%b7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b)
過去の質問↑で教えていただいたサイトにアライメント制約のないx86でもアラインされていないデータの読み出しはメモリアクセス回数が増えて実行速度が落ちるという趣旨の記述がありました。↓
[http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/~noocyte/Programming/Alignment.html#AlignmentTolerantCPU](http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Enoocyte/Programming/Alignment.html#AlignmentTolerantCPU)

そこで下記のようなコードを作成し、`time`コマンドで速度を図って試してみたのですが、実行速度に差がありませんでした
これは意図したとおりの検証になっているのでしょうか？（[rdi]がキャッシュされていて正しく検証できていないなど・・・）

```
section .text
global test

test:
    xor rax, rax
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    mov rax,  [rdi]
    ret
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

size_t test(char *s);

int main()
{
    char *s = "123456789abcdefghijklmn";
    uintptr_t i = (uintptr_t)s % 8;

    s += ((8 - i) % 8); //アライメントあり
    //s += !((8 - i) % 8); //アライメントなし
    printf("%p\n", s);

    long l = 0;
    while (l++ < INT_MAX)
        test(s);
}
```

これまでの自分の認識では
仮に以下のようなメモリの状態だった場合
（'|'はワード境界）

```
| * * '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' | '8' '9'
```

'2'のアドレスに対してロード命令で8byte raxに読み込んだ場合
raxの状態は

```
| * * '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' |
```

上記の様になる想定だった（CPUはワードサイズの倍数単位のアドレスでしかメモリにアクセスできないと思っていました）のですが、実際にコードを書いてみるとraxの下位1バイトは'2'になっていました
これまでは、アライメント制約がなくても実行速度上はアラインされていた方がいいのだろうと思っていましたが、もしかしてx86ではアライメントを気にする必要はほぼないのでしょうか？

例えば下記glibcのstrlenの実装では、最初にアライメントを揃える処理をしていますが、x86においてはこの処理は全く必要ないのでしょうか？
https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strlen.c

Comment: 回答を書くほど詳しくはないのですが、Ryzen 5 3600 だとコア内に64KBの1次キャッシュと512KBの2次キャッシュがあり、それらにヒットしている限りはアラインメントのペナルティはほぼ無いかもしれません。

Comment: アセンブリでメモリを指定してもキャッシュにちゃんと読みに行くんですね。奥が深いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> これは意図したとおりの検証になっているのでしょうか？（[rdi]がキャッシュされていて正しく検証できていないなど・・・）

アセンブリコードに関しては、その(疑問の)通り(で、検証になっていない)でしょうね。
同一アドレスのメモリを読み取っているだけなのでキャッシュに収まったままでしょうし、もっと言えば変化が無い同一の処理が並んでいるので実行がスキップされている可能性も考えられます。

例えば`rdi`は順次インクリメントして、`mov rax`ではなく`add rax`にする必要があるのでは？

---

> アライメント制約がなくても実行速度上はアラインされていた方がいいのだろうと思っていましたが、もしかしてx86ではアライメントを気にする必要はほぼないのでしょうか？

原理的にはアクセス回数の増加は発生していますが、多段階のキャッシュとか先読み/投機/パイプライン等の様々な手法によりハードウェアの高速化が図られています。1画面にも満たない一筆書きの20行程度の処理では違いがあったとしてもバラツキや誤差の範囲と変わらないかもしれません。

前回の回答にも紹介した通り、一部の例外的な命令/データや、性能競争とかスーパーコンピュータ的な用途のアプリケーションでない限り、アライメントを気にする必要はほぼないでしょう。

---

と、ここまで書いておいてひっくり返すようですが、コンパイラ(アセンブラも)ではデフォルトでそれなりのアライメント調節を行っています。
C++の標準仕様とかリリース用ビルド時の最適化などが関係しているのでしょう。

[align (C++)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=msvc-160)
[Alignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/alignment-cpp-declarations?view=msvc-160)

そういうことも含めて、大部分のアプリケーション/ライブラリ等は、細かいメモリアクセスのサイクル差ではなく、アルゴリズムとかの方を気にした方が良いと思われます。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。アセンブリでロード命令を書いてもcpuが実際にメモリに読みにいくとは限らないんですね。ありがとうございます。
アセンブリまでやればCPUのことも大体何でもわかるかと思っていましたが、もっとずっと奥が深そうですね。アライメントが無意味ではないということがわかったのでとてもすっきりしました。
調べてもあまり情報が出てこなくて答えにたどり着くのがとても難しいですね。

Answer (score 5):

既に解決済みなので、参考までに [CLFLUSH - Flush Cache Line](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/CLFLUSH.html) を使って `CPU cache(L1/L2/L3)` を flush してみます。

**実行環境**

```sh
$ LC_ALL=C lscpu | grep -E '(^(Architecture|Model name)|cache:)'
Architecture:          x86_64
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500T CPU @ 2.10GHz
L1d cache:             192 KiB
L1i cache:             192 KiB
L2 cache:              1.5 MiB
L3 cache:              9 MiB

$ lscpu | grep -Po 'clflush\S*'
clflush
clflushopt

$ uname -srmo
Linux 5.8.0-50-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0
```

**実行コード**

`CLFLUSH` ですが、実際には `__mm_clflush()` を使います。

**`main.c`**

```c
         :
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int main()
{
  alignas(8) char s[] = "123456789abcdefghijklmn";
  char *p = s;        // アライメントあり
  //char *p = s + 1;  // アライメントなし

  long l = 0;
  while (l++ < INT_MAX) {
    test(p);
    _mm_clflush(s);
  }
}
```

**実行時間**

以下、alignment あり・なし、CPU cache を flush しない・する場合での実行時間です。

```sh
$ gcc -O0 -o main main.c test.o
$ time taskset -c 5 ./main

## alignment あり(with cache)
##
real    0m9.306s
user    0m9.301s
sys     0m0.005s

## alignment あり(flush cache)
##
real    3m34.985s
user    3m34.968s
sys     0m0.014s

## alignment なし(with cache)
##
real    0m9.356s
user    0m9.352s
sys     0m0.005s

## alignment なし(flush cache)
##
real    3m39.436s
user    3m39.422s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Comment: 結構な違いが出るものなのですね。キャッシュ有効でも21億回?実行すれば50ミリ秒程度の差になるとは。

Comment: すごい～～～！ありがとうございます！こういうのが自分でやりたかったのですけど、試す方法が分かりませんでした！勉強になりましたっ！